# Little monoid from scratch example in Haskell with a bug while chaining the monoid

Tags: haskell, monads, monoids, do-notation

I think I have understood monoids *partly*. But I still have an issue. I don't know what Haskell wants from me in this case here. Why am I not able to chain my monad?

Code:

```hs
data Result a = Result a | Err String | Empty

instance Semigroup (Result a) where
           (Err a) <> _ = (Err a)
           _ <> (Err a) = (Err a)
           a <> b = b

instance Monoid (Result a) where
           mempty = Empty
           mappend = (<>)

initiate :: Result String
initiate = Result "initiated"

printResult :: Result String -> IO()
printResult (Result s) = putStr s

example :: Result String
example = do
           initiate -- if I remove one here, it will work
           initiate

main = printResult example
```

Error:

```
 ghc -o main main.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )

main.hs:20:12: error:
    * No instance for (Monad Result) arising from a do statement
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: initiate
      In the expression:
        do initiate
           initiate
      In an equation for `example':
          example
            = do initiate
                 initiate
   |
20 |            initiate
   |            ^^^^^^^^
exit status 1
```

Comment: `Monad`s and `Monoid`s are distinct notions (which are related only from the viewpoint of very abstract math -- you can pretend they are not related at all). On monoids, you can combine values using e.g. `initiate <> initiate <> initiate`, but you can not use `do` blocks for that.

Comment: You have created an instance of `Monoid` for `Result`, _not_ `Monad`. A monoid is not the same thing as a monad. You should read about what a monoid is and what a monad is and then reattempt your program.

Comment: If you remove one, the `do x` is just `x`. But it seems that you are mixin `Monad`s and `Monoid`s: a `Monad` requires implementing two different functions: `return` and `(>>=)`.

Comment: Thanks to you all. Seems I still mix them up :-) But yeah that makes sense to me

Comment: Just to note: `do foo` desugars to `foo` alone, whether or not monads are involved. Only a longer expression like `do { foo; bar }` triggers monad-specific desugaring to `foo >> bar`.

Comment: `Result () <> mempty` = `Empty` != `Result ()`, so this isn't a law-abiding `Monoid` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Summing up the comments, the issue here is that `Monoid` and `Monad` are distinct type classes with separate operations, as pointed out by @chi.  A `Monoid` of type `a` has an identity element:

```
mempty :: a
mempty = ...
```

and a binary operation (technically called `mappend`, but it should be identical to the `<>` from `Semigroup`):

```
(<>) :: a -> a -> a
x <> y = ...
```

while a `Monad` of type `m` has a `return` operation:

```
return :: a -> m a
```

and a bind operation:

```
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

For `Monad`s, a special `do` notation can be used in place of bind `(>>=)` operations, so that:

```
foo >>= f
```

and:

```
do x <- foo
   f x
```

are equivalent, but this `do` notation doesn't apply to `Monoid`s.  If you want to combine two `Monoid`s like `initiate`, you want to use the `<>` operator instead of trying to use `do` notation:

```
example = initiate <> initiate
```

As an aside, as @WillemVanOnsem points out, the reason your attempt with only one `initiate` worked:

```
example = do initiate
```

is that a one-line `do` block is a special case of `do` notation that doesn't really "do" anything, so it is equivalent to writing:

```
example = initiate
```

Anyway, if you write:

```
example = initiate <*> initiate
```

your program will compile and run.

However, as @DanielWagner points out, your `Monoid` isn't actually a correct monoid.  Monoids are supposed to obey certain laws.  You can find them near the top of the [documentation for `Data.Monoid`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.25/base-4.14.3.0/Data-Monoid.html#g:1).

One of the laws is that composition via `<>` with the `mempty` element shouldn't affect the non-`mempty` result, so we should have:

```
x <> mempty = x
mempty <> x = x
```

for all values `x`.  Your monoid doesn't obey this law because:

```
Result "foo" <> Empty = Empty
```

instead of the law-abiding result:

```
Result "foo" <> Empty = Result "foo"
```

What are the consequences?  Well, you might run into some unexpected behaviour when using Haskell library functions.  For example, the functions `foldMap` and `foldMap'` produce the same result; the only difference is that `foldMap'` is "strict" in the accumulator.  At least, that's true for law-abiding monoids.  For your monoid, they may give different answers:

```
> foldMap Result [1]
Empty
> foldMap' Result [1]
Result 1
```

It looks like you *can* produce a law-abiding monoid pretty easily.  You just need to handle `Empty` correctly before checking for `Err` and `Result`:

```
instance Semigroup (Result a) where
  Empty <> r = r
  r <> Empty = r
  Err a <> _ = Err a
  _ <> Err a = Err a
  a <> b = b
```

This can be simplified because some of these patterns overlap.  The following should be equivalent:

```
instance Semigroup (Result a) where
  Err a <> _ = Err a
  r <> Empty = r
  r1 <> r2 = r2
```

This monoid should consistently return the leftmost `Err` or, if there are no `Err`s at all, the rightmost `Result`, always ignoring any `Empty`s along the way.